# Sharded Tables Combined into a Single ActiveRecord Model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am new to Ruby on Rails (which may soon be obvious) and I'm trying to figure out a model for the following data scenario. I have read several posts and searched Google at length, but I'm still confused.

I have 5 different tables with identical columns, except the `value` column has a **different data type**. They data is in 5 separate tables for a variety of good reasons, but think of it as data sharded across multiple tables.

```
logbook_strings (user_id, entry_id, field_id, value) 
logbook_booleans (user_id, entry_id, field_id, value)  
logbook_integers (user_id, entry_id, field_id, value)  
logbook_decimals (user_id, entry_id, field_id, value)  
logbook_datetimes (user_id, entry_id, field_id, value)
```

So here's what the data would look like:

```
------------------------------------------------
| user_id | entry_id | field_id | value        |
------------------------------------------------
| 1       | alpha1   | date     | 2012-11-14   |
| 1       | alpha1   | duration | 1.2          |
| 1       | alpha1   | remarks  | Nice job.    |
------------------------------------------------
| 1       | alpha2   | date     | 2012-11-13   |
| 1       | alpha2   | duration | 2.7          |
| 1       | alpha2   | remarks  | Bad job.     |
------------------------------------------------
```

**Entry alpha1:**
2012-11-14, 1.2, Nice Job.

**Entry alpha2:**
2012-11-13, 2.7, Bad job.

etc.

The reason I do this is so that I can have an infinitely flexible database. I can add a new `field_id` at any time to add a new field/feature to my app instead of doing a schema update to add yet another column to a wide logbook table.

So what I'm wondering, is there a way I can have a single ActiveRecord model in which I can reference all 5 of these tables?

Comment: To clarify, what methods would you like to call if such a model existed? Something like this: lb = Logbook.new; lb.int_value = 10; lb.string_value = "foo"?

Comment: Good question. In my app, I have logbook entries that have around 25-30 values in each entry. Instead of having a "logbook entries" table with a ton of columns (and a gnarly schema to manage), I instead use the above-mentioned `entry_id` and `field_id` like this:

Comment: It cut off the code, unfortunately. Maybe put it in pastebin or github gist and include the link to it? Or update your question with it would work too.

Comment: See this link (easier than fiddling with SO's comment box): http://d.pr/n/Mxc8

Comment: So to answer your question, yes, I would query the database and insert data into it similar to what you've recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending a few minutes trying to shoehorn this into a single ActiveRecord class, I don't think it's a great idea to use ActiveRecord for something like this. I see a few options:

- Roll your own model. The extreme downside to this approach is that you lose out on all of ActiveRecord's many nice features. But if your data is relatively simple (not a lot of associations, etc.) then this might be a viable option.
- Restructure your data. If this schema/data is either pre-existing or has to match a mobile app's schema for some reason or another, this might not be an option. But if you're starting fresh, Rails' migrations make adding/removing columns on a whim extremely easy and very safe so I might consider using a more traditional approach. While this may not seem ideal, it's something to seriously consider in order to gain the many benefits of ActiveRecord.

If you must keep your schema, creating a separate model for each logbook table could be your best option.

```
# Migrations
create_table :logbook do |t|
  # Default fields, nothing special
end

create_table :logbook_integers do |t|
  t.integer :logbook_id  # You'd probably want to index this as well
  t.string :name
  t.integer :value
end

create_table :logbook_strings do |t|
  t.integer :logbook_id   # You'd probably want to index this as well
  t.string :name
  t.string :value
end

# etc...

# Models
class Logbook < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :logbook_integers
  has_many :logbook_strings
  # etc...

  def remarks
    self.logbook_strings.find_by_name("remarks").value
  end

  def remarks= newValue
    remark = self.logbook_strings.find_or_create_by_name("remarks")
    remark.value = newValue
    remark.save
  end

  # etc...
end

class LogbookInteger < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :logbook
end

class LogbookString < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :logbook
end

# etc...

# Usage

logbook = Logbook.new
logbook.remarks = "Hi"
logbook.duration = 2

logbook.remarks         # => Hi
logbook.duration        # => 2
```

If you can change your schema a bit, here's an option:

You can use the `serialize` class method [described here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) (cmd+f for 'serialize') to store your entries so instead of having many models, you just have two: `Logbook` and `LogbookField`. It might look something like this:

```
# Migration for logbook_fields
create_table :logbook_fields do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.string :value
end

# Models
class Logbook
  has_many :logbook_fields

  def self.build_with_default_fields
    self.logbook_fields.create name: "date"
    self.logbook_fields.create name: "duration"
    # etc...
  end

  # You could probably do some cool Ruby metaprogramming to create all these
  # accessors/setters for you, btw.
  def date
    self.logbook_fields.find_by_name "date"
  end

  def date= newValue
    field = self.logbook_fields.find_by_name "date"
    field.value = newValue
    field.save
  end


  def duration
    self.logbook_fields.find_by_name "duration"
  end

  def duration= newValue
    field = self.logbook_fields.find_by_name "duration"
    field.value = newValue
    field.save
  end

  # etc...

end

class LogbookField
  serialize :value

  belongs_to :logbook
end

# Usage

logbook = Logbook.build_with_default_fields
logbook.date = DateTime.now
logbook.duration = 2.7
```

Something to that effect. That way you retain most all the ActiveRecord niceties while still maintaining some of the "infinite-ness" of your schema design. However, adding/removing columns on a single table with migrations would probably prove easier than this even. Again, it depends on whether you can be flexible in your schema or not. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have given this a ton of thought, and I've decided it's going to be simpler and easier in the end to simplify my database schema. I'm going to go with a single `logbook` table and just have a column for each "attribute" in my app. Migrations certainly make this easy, though I have to grapple with schema changes on SQLite on an iOS device, but that shouldn't be too bad. Thanks a ton for your help!

Comment: No problem! I wouldn't wish manual SQLite schema changes on anyone, though. If you're somehow syncing the apps using Rails as a JSON web service or something, you could attempt to keep the iOS schema and just come up with a way to serialize the JSON into a format both the web server and the iOS device understand. That way, you could leave the schemas different on both devices. Not sure if that's what you're trying to do, but just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should probably have a one table with a type column.

Ex:

```
logbook(user_id, entry_id, field_id, value, value_type)
```

value type would be

```
strings

booleans  

integers 

decimals 

datetimes
```

Example would be

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
| user_id | entry_id | field_id | value        |value_type |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| 1       | alpha1   | date     | 2012-11-14   | datetime 
| 1       | alpha1   | duration | 1.2          | decimal
| 1       | alpha1   | remarks  | Nice job.    | string
```

So basically value column will be string, and from the model you could decide what you wanted to with the value type, your model would be

```
class Logbook < ActiveRecord::Base

   #sample method
   #just to give an idea how you could use the same value
   #with different times
   def multiple_duration_by_two
     self.value * 2  if self.value_type == "decimal"
   end

end
```

However, depending on your requirements this implementation might need tweeks, but I guess you get the idea

HTH

Comment: That's an interesting idea--something I thought about, but I'd be doing a heck of a lot of type casting in some of my queries. I'll give it some thought, though.

Comment: cool, But if you are using ActiveRecord joins insted of normal queries I guess your life will be easier :), infact, if you do this method or another method, I advise you to use ActiveRecord joins and relationships over normal sql queries, coz then later you could leverage the full power or AR, HTH